# About Operating system States

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, scheduling, cpu-architecture, multitasking

In a non-preemptive CPU scheduling scheme, can the scheduling take place when a process 
or thread switches from the waiting state to the ready state? Why

Answer (score 1):

> In a non-preemptive CPU scheduling scheme, can the scheduling take place when a process or thread switches from the waiting state to the ready state?

Yes, but only if a CPU is idle; otherwise (if all CPUs have a currently running task and none are idle) you'd have to preempt a currently running task (and it wouldn't be non-preemptive).

Comment: I guess we're ruling out the case where a running task just happened to be making a `yield()` or `schedule()` call (e.g. in a long running loop with no other system calls) at the instant another task became runnable.